# Confused! Trying to MP3 metadata in EZiest way possible, Preferably without extra libs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I've searched all over google, here, HTML5Rocks, etc...
Everywhere I look I get "half" an answer or told to use some other lengthy lib that doesn't even work with what i'm trying to do.

I've made a full jQueryUI plug for making a simple audio player, the last step is filling the playlist from an option like:

```
playlist: [
    '<?= base_url("audio/samp/Kalimba.mp3"); ?>',
    '<?= base_url("audio/samp/Maid_with_the_Flaxen_Hair.mp3"); ?>',
    '<?= base_url("audio/samp/Sleep_Away.mp3"); ?>'
]
```

Where in the plugin I have something like:

```
for (x in ele.playlist) { 
    //  get meta data for song title, artist, album, & length 
    //  so I can add it to button inside li
    //  example: in a callback where param for AudioContext is audon
    //  audcon.button() // call to saved jQuery object of list item button
    //      .prepend($("<p /">).text(dataReturned.songTitle))  //  add element to button with text of song title
}
```

Of course, i've found part of the issue is, this for loop runs faster than the time it takes to read a file, which I should think is no problem as long as I can use a call back. For example, using HTML5, I add the button html as a property to my AudioContext, so that when it finishes reading, I can easily access the li button that duration belongs on.

Can anyone give a simple, clear cut example of how to achieve what I want, cause none of what i've tried is getting me anywhere.

I have found pretty ez how to use HTML5 to get the duration of each song and use a callback to put the duration in each button after its loaded, but the duration doesn't really tell a user much about the song loaded other than how long it is, lol.

Comment: $list is PHP - do you have server scripting in this? Perhaps including all of your code will help.

Comment: @Anna Billstrom no, I just use the $ as marker for my temp vars i'll change names too later

Comment: @AnnaBillstrom `$list` is a perfectly valid JS variable name as well. :) But you're right, OP is clearly using php to echo the `base_url` of the `mp3` files. I've never tried to do this in JS/PHP, but I'll +1 as it's pretty interesting and should be possible.

Comment: So the idea is to populate the <UL> with a JS array? Still confused on basic problem.

Comment: To extract MP3 metadata, without using external libs, you need to write one such library yourself... I think you are fighting against windmills here. HTMLAudio element does not expose all this info. Just get your libs working on the server-side, that's your actual issue right?

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed it's a matter of reading the data/binary, was hoping someone might have a simple exersize to that